# Diffeomorphism on the image

Tags: analysis

Let $\Phi(x,y)=(x^2+2ycosx+1, sinx+e^{x+y})$. Proof that exists neighborhood $U$ of the point $(0,0)$ such that $\Phi_{|U}$ is diffeomorphism on the image. Calculate the derivative $(\Phi_{|U})^{-1})$ in $(1,1)$.

Well, im struggling with this task. Idea was:

$1-1:$

$(\Phi(x,y)=\Phi(t1,t2)$ for $(t1,t2)\in \mathbb R^{2}$

$\begin{cases}
  x^2+2ycosx+1 = (t1)^2+2(t2)cos(t1)+1 \\
  sinx+e^{x+y} = sin(t1) + e^{t1+t2}
\end{cases}$

What now? ... Or maybe it's obvious, because I have to do this in $(0,0)$ point?

$\Phi(x,y)=\Phi(t1,t2)=(0,0) :$

$\begin{cases}
  0+0+1 = 0+0+1 \\
  0+1 = 0+1
\end{cases}$

(I think this is stupid a little bit and idk if I am doing it right)

$C^{1}:$

$D\Phi(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}
    2x-2ysinx & 2cosx  \\
    cosx +e^{x+y} & e^{x+y}  \\
    \end{pmatrix}$

All functions are continuous, so it's $C^{1}$

$detD\Phi(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}
    2x-2ysinx & 2cosx  \\
    cosx +e^{x+y} & e^{x+y}  \\
    \end{pmatrix} = (2x-2ysinx)e^{x+y} - 2cosx(cosx +e^{x+y}) \not= 0$

for all $(x,y)$ especially in $(0,0)$

To find $(\Phi)^{-1}$ I would do something like that:

$\begin{cases}
  u = x^2+2ycosx+1  \\
  v = sinx+e^{x+y}
\end{cases}$

Find here $x,y$, check if $\Phi(u,v)=(x(u,v),y(u,v))$ is continuous, calculate derivatives and put it into matrix, then check if determinant is $\not=0$. That would show that this function is diffeomorphism. But how should i calculate in  $(\Phi_{|U})^{-1}$? Should I do following steps and then make something like this?

\begin{pmatrix}
    \frac{d}{dx}\phi_1(u,v) & \frac{d}{dx}\phi_2(u,v)  \\
    \frac{d}{dy}\phi_1(u,v) & \frac{d}{dy}\phi_(u,v)  \\
    \end{pmatrix}

Edit: This matrix is wrong i think, i should use Jacobi's matrix here propably

Propably this is completly wrong, so please give me advice :(

Answer (score 1):

Somehow, you think to complicated. Why are you using $t_1$ and $t_2$?

If you checked that $\Phi$ is differentiable, you can compute the Jacobian matrix $J_{\Phi}(x,y)$ of $\Phi$ at $(x,y)$ and you get
$$
J_{\Phi}(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}
2x-2y\sin(x) & 2\cos(x)\\
\cos(x)+e^{x+y} & e^{x+y}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and further
$$
J_{\Phi}(0,0)=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 2\\2&1\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Since $\det\left(J_{\Phi}(0,0)\right)=-4\neq 0$, there exists a neighbourhood $U$ of $(0,0)$ such that 
$$
\Phi\mid_U:U\to V:=\Phi(U)
$$
is bijective and $\det(J_{\Phi}(x,y))\neq 0$ for all $(x,y)\in U$. Hence $\Phi^{-1}$ is differentiable on $V$ with
$$
J_{\Phi^{-1}}(\Phi(x,y))=\left(J_{\Phi}(x,y)\right)^{-1}.
$$
*(This should be a theorem in your lecture)*

Now, you can compute
$$
J_{\Phi^{-1}}(1,1)=J_{\Phi^{-1}}(\Phi(0,0))=\ldots
$$

Comment: "If you checked that Φ is differentiable". How to do it? I have to show that this function is 1-1? This system of equations looks bad... Yeah I've made Jacobian matrix, but in my lecture we call it "D", not "J".

Comment: Now, to find $J\Phi^{−1}(1,1)$, I have to find $x,y$ from $u=x^{2}+2ycos(x)+1, v=sin(x)+e^{x+y}$ equation? I am confused here. Or if u said, that $J\Phi^{−1}(1,1)$ = $J\Phi^{−1}(0,0)$, so the correct answer is just to find inverse matrix, so $J\Phi^{−1}(1,1) = -\frac{1}{4}\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & -2  \\
   -2 & 0  \\
    \end{pmatrix}$$ ??

Comment: $\Phi$ is differentiable as composition of differentiable functions, so it is sufficient to mention it. And the bijectivity of $\Phi\mid_U$ comes from a theorem, you should have in your lecture. Check it out. The theorem claims the existence of $\Phi^{-1}$ but that doesn't mean, that you can get it with a nice explicit formula. But in your case, you don't need it. As the formula for the Jacobian of $\Phi^{-1}$ says, you just have to compute the matrix inverse of the Jacobian of $\Phi$ at the correct point.

Comment: "$\Phi$ is differentiable as composition of differentiable function". Of course it is!...Theorem on the inverse function... Yea I got it now. Well, is my matrix inverse correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping!